# How to cancel Constraint "Track to" for a specific keyframe

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, constraints

So I'm having my camera follow my spaceship around and at the end of the scene I want it to stop. On that keyframe, I want it to stay at the view it was positioned at before I cancelled it but when I do, it just goes wherever and I have to manually position it, which doesn't get too good of a result and looks funny when I put the image strip in video editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the camera to the final position first, before adding the *Track to* constraint, there is a solution. On the *Track to* constraint, there is a slider labeled *Influence:* (shown below). It decides how much control the constraint has over the camera's direction.

[image]

Turn the *Influence:* to *0* and position the camera how you want it on the final frame. Turn it back to *1*. Move the cursor in the *Timeline* panel to the frame just before the one where you want the camera to stop moving. Hover over the *Influence:* slider and key <kbd>I</kbd>; it should change from grey to yellow. Move to the next frame in the *Timeline* panel. Move the slider down to *0*. Hover and key <kbd>I</kbd> again. The slider should change color from green to yellow.

*A sample of the method used (note how the slider changes):*

[image]

The .blend with the cube can be found below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Track To constraint has a value slider called Influence, that goes from 0 (no effect) to 1 ( full effect) you can keyframe this as much as any other value in Blender.
Selecting the camera, go to Constraints panel, go to the last frame you want the Track To constraint to have effect in, mouseover that value, press <kbd>i</kbd> it turns yellow and adds a keyframe, go to the frame you want to elliminate the constraint's effect in, change the value to 0, and repeat the previous operation to add a keyframe.